# Can't access database on the remote server

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, entity-framework, remote-server

I am a newbie, so bear with me. I have a SQL Server database located on a remote server. In Visual Studio 2010, I was able to create an entity data model (which contained user credentials so it designed remote database schema) and a simple WCF service. In localhost, I was able to fetch and retrieve data. But, after I published the ASP.NET project, I noticed that I can't query the same database. Both the database and the application files are now on the same server.

What could be the reason as to why the local environment can query the remote server but the deployed app can't? Do I need to reconfigure the data model or something else?

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Check the connectionstring placed in the web.config for the following:</strike>

- userid and password> Are they filled?
- data source> Does this point to the server?

Check the error messages. What message does the WCF service return?

Silverlight crossdomain access file.

Create a new textfile and name it **clientaccesspolicy.xml** and put it in the root of your webproject.

File content:
(This allowed all and everyone, must be tweaked off course :D)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<access-policy>
  <cross-domain-access>
    <policy>
      <allow-from http-request-headers="*">
        <domain uri="*"/>
      </allow-from>
      <grant-to>
        <resource path="/" include-subpaths="true"/>
      </grant-to>
    </policy>
  </cross-domain-access>
</access-policy>
```

Comment: Yes and yes! Here is part of the error message I am getting: CrossDomainError. Debugging resource strings are unavailable.

Comment: The stack trace is too long, but the error message displays methods like EndCall, EndInvoke, EndGetSomething

Comment: With what are you connecting to the WCF service? Silverlight by any chance? Have you checked if other (non db) methods work?

Comment: Yeah, its Silverlight. No, I haven't. I just learned that I need to set up some cross domain xml files.

Comment: That would be my next suggestion :D